# Why does putting a tsquery inside a WITH suddenly make it take 2x as long? (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, indexing, common-table-expression

I have a very simple query:

```sql
SELECT count(*) FROM link_list ll
WHERE ll.tsvector @@ to_tsquery('english', 'advertising|slogan|publicity|ads|advertise|brand|promo|ad|propaganda|sales|promote|logo|hype|commercial|consumerism|pamphlet|viral|salesperson|selling|blurb|advert|merchandise|marking|products|campaign|packaging|billboard|advertisement|promotion|questionnaire|marketing')
```

It runs fast (Here's the output from [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/anUT)). It uses the GIN index, and works exactly as expected.

Life is good.

But now, let me tweak the query slightly, and now it takes 2x as long!

```sql
WITH query AS
(
   SELECT to_tsquery('english',('advertising|slogan|publicity|ads|advertise|brand|promo|ad|propaganda|sales|promote|logo|hype|commercial|consumerism|pamphlet|viral|salesperson|selling|blurb|advert|merchandise|marking|products|campaign|packaging|billboard|advertisement|promotion|questionnaire|marketing')) query
)
SELECT count(*) FROM link_list ll
WHERE ll.tsvector @@ (SELECT query FROM query);
```

(Output from [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/aMO))

I *would* just use the first query... but unfortunately, the list of synonyms has to be dynamically generated, which I pull from another table.

For some strange reason, putting the `tsquery` inside `WITH` makes Postgresql not use the index as efficiently (It thinks it'll be a quick and dirty job that doesn't need an index, and it ends up being dead wrong).

Why in the world is this happening??

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: PostgreSQL 12.9

Comment: The two plans are pretty much identical with the exception that the first one uses a parallel query, and thus the performance advantage. It's probably a limitation regarding the use of parallel query in combination with CTEs. I highly doubt it, but does it change if you use a `VALUES` clause, instead of a `SELECT` inside the CTE?

Comment: No, changing the CTE to using `VALUES` has almost no difference. I guess the only solution is to run two concurrent queries: one to grab the synonyms from a table, and another to perform the full-text search. It sucks because I'm querying another server -- so, two queries is going to introduce quite a bit of lag -- but combining the queries adds an additional 10 seconds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither one of those executions seems all that fast.

Your use of the WITH inhibits the parallel plan.  If your bottleneck is IO (which seems likely) you can get parallel IO without parallel query by setting effective_io_concurrency to a value > 1.

The time spent setting up JIT is over 10% of the faster plan, and is probably a complete waste.  You can `set jit = off` (or turn it off globally in the .conf file) to spare that time.

Your recheck of lossy blocks also wastes time.  You should increase work_mem to get rid of those.  But the waste is of mostly CPU time, so the effect will be small if the bottleneck is IO, not CPU.  It still has to visit the same set of blocks.  (An exception to this is if TOAST is heavily used, then rows not rechecked don't need to be assembled from TOAST, so those TOAST block reads are avoided.)

Comment: Thank you! I've been meaning to increase work_mem, but I was a afraid to do so because I read that increasing it can lead to crashes... but I guess it can't be avoided in this case.